# Почему fgetcsv не видит переносов строк при чтении csv файла

Tags: php

Всем привет. 
**Помогите пожалуйста.**

Мне нужно прочитать простой csv файл (кодировка UTF-8).
При чтении одной строки функция fgetcsv получает данные других строк. Почему так получается ? Как мне получить названия колонок ?

```
$f = fopen($file_path, "r");
$csv = fgetcsv($f, 3000, ";");

foreach ($csv as $column) {
  echo 'Column: ' . $column . '<br>';
}

fclose($f);
```

[image: Результат получаю следующий]

Если этот же файл например открыть в libreoffice и пересохранить в UTF-8, то при чтении все хорошо.

Ссылка на файл который необходимо причитать csv: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Sz19jAG8_f1p7hiPVTtFaOLGTOW3uLmp

Comment: У меня все прекрасно отработало, хм.. [демо](https://repl.it/@wnull/testings)

Comment: Да, в демо работает. А вы файл csv пересохраняли ?

Comment: вроде с 1 раза вышло)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас в файле строки разделены символами CR, а требуется LF или CR+LF.

[Перевод строк](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8)

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Действительно файл содержит символы CR. Очень помогли.